# Is possible to add css animations to cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am trying to create a animated flow diagram, where the data flow path has to be shown in Animation similar to [this](https://codepen.io/superpikar/pen/Gjomxp)

I want to know is this possible in cytoscape, or any other library recommended for this. 
My objective is to create presentations in reveal.js with animated flow diagrams.

```
.animation-slow{ animation: arc-animation 100s linear infinite; }
.animation-medium{ animation: arc-animation 50s linear infinite; }
.animation-fast{ animation: arc-animation 10s linear infinite; }

.animation{
  stroke-dasharray: 5px 10px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
}

@keyframes arc-animation {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

.arc-information{
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em #cecece;
  background: white;
  display: table !important;
  tr td{ padding: 3px 10px; }
  tr th{ background: #FFEB3B; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the animation functions or stylesheet transitions:

- Core : http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/animation
- Collection : http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/animation
- Transitions : http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/transition-animation

Comment: I'm slightly confused how you would translate between the CSS `animate` property and a call to `cy.animate()`. Where would I reference my keyframe?